# How to trim text before specifc character using notepad++

Tags: notepad++, string, trim

I have a file each line look like "J001.C1086"   "JH001.Blend 10-111".  I need to remove the leter/number before each .

after remove, it look like "C1086"   "Blend 10-111"

Thanks!!

Comment: Is it good enough to remove everything though the first dot (**``.``**)?

Comment: Teach a man to fish - [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
 - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
 - [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
 - [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
 - [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
 - [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In `Notepad++` you can use Regex on the Find menu.

In this case, you would go to Search > Replace or `Ctrl + H` to open up the Find & Replace menu.

You will need to tick `Regular expression` under the `Search Mode` at the bottom.

It is important to be as specific as possible when using Regex - judging by your query, I will remove any text before the full-stop, inclusive.

In the **Find what:** field, paste the following:

`^.*\.(.*)$`

In the **Replace with:** field, place the following:

`$1`

The `$1` is replacing everything on the line with anything inside the brackets!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed Regular Expression is your friend and is very efficient to learn.

In your case, find:

```
^\w+\.
```

Replace by nothing using ReGeX.

This should work.

Btw this means you search for the beginning of a line (^), followed by at least one (+) alpha numeric character (\w) and a period (\.).